# Error when i install mysql + galera

Tags: mysql, centos6.5, galera

I want install **mysql server + galera** in my vps Centos 6.5. When I install

```
yum update -y && yum install wget libevent perl mysql-y
wget https://launchpad.net/codership-mysql/5.6/5.6.16-25.5/+download/MySQL-server-5.6.16_wsrep_25.5-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
wget https://launchpad.net/galera/3.x/25.3.5/+download/galera-25.3.5-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh --force MySQL-server-5.6.16_wsrep_25.5-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh galera-25.3.5-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

terminal show:

```
[root@db1 ~]# /etc/init.d/mysql status ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists
[root@db1 ~]# rm -rf /var/lock/subsys/mysql 
[root@db1 ~]# /etc/init.d/mysql start
Starting MySQL. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/db1.pid).
[root@db1 ~]# cat /var/lib/mysql/db1.err 
140517 11:19:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140517 11:19:56 mysqld_safe WSREP: Running position recovery with --log_error='/var/lib/mysql/wsrep_recovery.zt0hQM' --pid-file='/var/lib/mysql/db1-recover.pid'
2014-05-17 11:19:57 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
140517 11:19:57 mysqld_safe WSREP: Failed to recover position:  2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error. 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed. 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [ERROR] Aborting 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Binlog end 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'wsrep' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog' 2014-05-17 11:19:57 10980 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

This is my my.cnf

```
[root@db1 ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf 
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
```

**¿How can i install galera + mysql?*

Answer (score 0):

There error is due to MySQL client missing. You also need to install `mysql-client` package.

Comment: Mysql not fixes the problem :(